React flow - auto scroll on drag to select more nodes
I'm using the reactflow library and need to select multiple nodes by clicking and dragging. However, when the cursor moves outside the container during selection, the process stops.
I want the container to auto-scroll in this scenario, similar to how it behaves when dragging a node near the edge of the container, where it automatically scrolls.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hello Andrei, did you find a solution ?

UPDATE: I recently updated React Flow to v12 (xyFlow/react), and now I’m encountering an issue where the bounding box (selection box) remains on the screen after trying to select items with click and drag out of the screen. Additionally, the canvas doesn’t autoscroll when I attempt to move it while dragging. It seems like the selection behavior and canvas movement aren’t functioning also in the new update.
